# How to update a database after a DataGridComboBoxColumn has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a wpf datagrid that is bound to one dataset and has two combobox columns that take their values form the main dataset and has options from two different databases, in every other cell (which are regular textbox cells) once editing is finished the database is updated through an dataset.DataTable.RowChanged event, the problem is the two other columns aren't part of the same datatable (even though they take their value from that datatable) and so doesn't call the same function that is called when their value is changed. Also, I can't find an event that is called when the value is changed (only before it changes).

What can I do to get an event whenever a combobox inside a datagrid is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, it appears that the update method is invoked (popped a MessageBox to check) and the algorithm had an issue when it was sent form the combobox.